# Inherit values from more general selector

Tags: css

Having the following styles defined:

```
h1 {
  margin-bottom: 2em;
}

h1:last-child {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

If I have an h1 element that is a last child for which I want to apply the margin-bottom of the normal h1 elements, is there a better way than to define the margin-bottom of 2em again explicitly for this element?

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use CSS variable:

```css
h1 {
  margin-bottom: var(--b,2em);
}

h1:last-child {
  --b: 0; /* override the default 2em */
}

h1.custom {
  --b:initial; /* get back to the default 2em*/
}


div {
  border:1px solid;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <h1>some text</h1>
</div>

<div>
  <h1 class="custom">some text</h1>
</div>
```